# Uploading large files - Creating chunks on UI vs backend?

Tags: javascript, performance, amazon-s3, file-upload, architecture

I have a question, what is the best practice between these two approaches considering we need to upload large files?

**First Approach:**

Reading a file & creating chunks (slice of a file i.e. blob) on UI and sending each chunk to the backend from the UI.

On the Backend read each chunk as streams & send each chunk to the desired place (s3).

If we receive all chunks of data in the backend, assemble the chunks at the desired place (s3).

Benefits:

- Fewer chances of timeouts (considering large file).
- Ease of retries which reduces chances of errors (we can resend the chunk in case of failure).

Disadvantage:

- It will consume more memory on the UI (creating chunks).

**Second Approach:**

Reading the whole file from the UI, reading the file chunk by chunk on the backend & uploading the chunks at the desired place (s3), and assembling the parts.

Advantages:

- Less memory on the UI.

Disadvantages:

- More timeouts & more error-prone.

Could you please help me in deciding the best approach? I understand the solution depends upon the use case to use case, but please note we want to enable users to upload larger files.

Answer (score 0):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor     incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation     ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit     in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat     non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).